# Fallo al publicar wordpress en mac

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, macos

He instalado wordpress (v- 5.1.1) en un mac utilizando xampp con php en la versión 7.1.28

He creado un tema básico vacío y la web carga sin problemas pero a la hora de intentar crear una página me salta el error del título por lo que supongo que debe ser algún tema de permisos, aunque he probado a dar permisos de escritura y lectura de manera recursiva al directorio htdocs y sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.

He comprobado en el error y en el access log y no hay ningún registro que me de información de lo que pueda estar fallando.

He probado a subir una imagen después de asignar los permisos y me deja subirla aunque sigue sin dejarme crear la página. No he añadido ningún plugin y todo está actualizado a la última versión. También descarto que sea un problema del tema porque con el resto de temas por defecto sigue saliendo el error.

Algún consejo o alguien que le haya ocurrido? En windows nunca había tenido este problema por lo que entiendo que debe estar fallando algo referente al sistema operativo, algún paso que me falte. Gracias

He probado a instalar MAMP y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Damos por supuesto que has instalado la versión de XAMPP para Mac. ¿Correcto? También sería bueno que subieses el error que nos mencionas. Activar el modo debug de Wordpress para tener más información también puede ser una buena opción.

Comment: @phpMyGuel Sí, he instalado el dmg del xampp para mac, el wp_debug esta activado pero no salta ningún error, sin embargo no puedo añadir o modificar ninguna página, ni si quiera la que viene por defecto. El usuario de la base de datos tiene todos los permisos asignados y no navego desde proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era simple, aunque me ha llevado un tiempo darme cuenta.

Hay que entrar en `Ajustes > Enlaces Permanentes` y simplemente darle a `Guardar Cambios`. Debe ser que en la base de datos no se actualizan las referencias de los enlaces por algún motivo y al guardar los enlaces permanentes se vuelven a generar y funciona. Supongo que este problema asciende también a los usuarios de Windows ya que parece un fallo del propio wordpress.